# Problem with organizing and accessing data in xml database - VB.Net

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, xmldocument

So I made an XML database for my music player where I store songs data (title,artist,album,genre,year) the code for generating the database is working but slow as heck, the code works as following diagram.

```
                                       
                                       |Aritsts Database  >|Aritst ->(Name,Songs,Count)
Music Library -->For Loop> Xml Database|Albums  Database  >|Album  ->(Name,Songs,Count)
                                       |Genres  Database  >|Genre  ->(Name,Songs,Count)
                                       |Years   Database  >|Year   ->(Name,Songs,Count)
```

Example for the artist database (the rest for albums , years , genres  will be the same)
So what am doing is looping through the music library and storing the artist , album , genre , year in 4 separate `List(Of String)` Then I remove the duplicates from the list, then I make a `List(Of String)`(Song list) Then I loop on all the Artist XML database which is loaded in a `XMLDocument` If the Artist is already there it will add the songs to the current artist else It will make a new artist node and add the songs to it
The only problem is It's too slow I think it's a problem with the code but I don't know how to fix it.Here is the code:

```vb
   Dim OldCount As Double = My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Count
                My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Clear()
                Dim filters As String = "*.mp3|*.wav|*.aiff|*.mp2|*.mp1|*.ogg|*.wma|*.flac|*.alac|*.webm"
                For Each path In My.Settings.librarypath
                    Dim files
                    If My.Settings.DirectoryTopOpen = True Then
                        files = filters.Split("|"c).SelectMany(Function(filter) System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filter, IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).ToArray()
                    Else
                        files = filters.Split("|"c).SelectMany(Function(filter) System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filter, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray()
                    End If
                    For Each file In files
                        My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Add(file)
                    Next
                Next
                Dim ArtistList As New List(Of String)
                Dim AlbumList As New List(Of String)
                Dim Tagger = Nothing
                For Each track In My.Settings.MusicLibrary
                    Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(track)
                    ArtistList.Add(Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers)
                    AlbumList.Add(Tagger.Tag.Album)
                    Tagger = Nothing
                Next
                Dim NartistList = ArtistList.Distinct.ToList
                Dim NalbumList = AlbumList.Distinct.ToList
                My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Clear()
                My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Clear()
                For Each artist In NartistList
                    My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Add(artist)
                Next
                For Each album In NalbumList
                    My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Add(album)
                Next
                Dim _Tagger
                For Each song In My.Settings.MusicLibrary
                    _Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                    My.Forms.Form1.Library_Main.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({_Tagger.Tag.Title, _Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers, _Tagger.Tag.Album, _Tagger.Properties.Duration.TotalMinutes.ToString.Substring(0, 4).Replace(".", ":"), _Tagger.Tag.Year, _Tagger.Properties.AudioBitrate, _Tagger.Properties.AudioChannels, _Tagger.Properties.AudioSampleRate, _Tagger.Properties.BitsPerSample, _Tagger.Properties.MediaTypes.ToString, song}))
                Next
                settings_rebuildlib.Checked = False
                My.Forms.Form1.ShowNotification("Scanner", "Added " & My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Count - OldCount & " To the library", "Mr.Audio • Settings • Scanner", My.Resources.radar1, Color.DodgerBlue)
                UpdateLibStatistics()
```

```vb
  Dim WithEvents BG_LIB_UPDATOR As New BackgroundWorker With {.WorkerReportsProgress = True, .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True}
    Public Sub UpdateLibStatistics()
        Library_upd_overlay.Visible = True
        Library_upd_overlay.BringToFront
        BG_LIB_UPDATOR.RunWorkerAsync()
```

```vb
  Private Sub BG_SCANER_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BG_SCANER.DoWork
        BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(0)
        Try
            Dim NewSongs As New List(Of String)
            If settings_scanlib.Checked = True Then
                Dim OldCount As Double = My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Count
                Dim OldLibrary As String()
                ReDim OldLibrary(OldCount - 1)
                My.Settings.MusicLibrary.CopyTo(OldLibrary, 0)
                My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Clear()
                Dim filters As String = "*.mp3|*.wav|*.aiff|*.mp2|*.mp1|*.ogg|*.wma|*.flac|*.alac|*.webm"
                For Each path In My.Settings.librarypath
                    Dim files
                    If My.Settings.DirectoryTopOpen = True Then
                        files = filters.Split("|"c).SelectMany(Function(filter) System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filter, IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).ToArray()
                    Else
                        files = filters.Split("|"c).SelectMany(Function(filter) System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filter, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray()
                    End If
                    For Each file In files
                        If OldLibrary.Contains(file) Then
                            My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Add(file)
                        Else
                            NewSongs.Add(file)
                            My.Settings.MusicLibrary.Add(file)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
                Dim ArtistList As New List(Of String)
                Dim AlbumList As New List(Of String)
                Dim Tagger = Nothing
                For Each track In My.Settings.MusicLibrary
                    Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(track)
                    ArtistList.Add(Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers)
                    AlbumList.Add(Tagger.Tag.Album)
                    Tagger = Nothing
                Next
                Dim NartistList = ArtistList.Distinct.ToList
                Dim NalbumList = AlbumList.Distinct.ToList
                My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Clear()
                My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Clear()
                For Each artist In NartistList
                    My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Add(artist)
                Next
                For Each album In NalbumList
                    My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Add(album)
                Next
                BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(20)
                'Updating Lib stats
                For Each track In My.Settings.MusicLibrary
                    Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(track)
                    ArtistList.Add(Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers)
                    AlbumList.Add(Tagger.Tag.Album)
                    Tagger = Nothing
                Next
                NartistList = ArtistList.Distinct.ToList
                NalbumList = AlbumList.Distinct.ToList
                My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Clear()
                My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Clear()
                My.Settings.YearLibrary.Clear()
                My.Settings.GenreLibrary.Clear()
                For Each artist In NartistList
                    My.Settings.ArtistLibrary.Add(artist)
                Next
                For Each album In NalbumList
                    My.Settings.AlbumLibrary.Add(album)
                Next
                'Updating XML files
                Dim LIB_ARTISTtpath As String = ""
                Dim LIB_ALBUMtpath As String = ""
                Dim LIB_YEARtpath As String = ""
                Dim LIB_GENREtpath As String = ""
                Dim ErrorList As New List(Of String)
                If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Artists.xml")) Then
                    LIB_ARTISTtpath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Artists.xml")
                Else
                    ErrorList.Add("LIB_ARTISTS")
                End If
                If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Albums.xml")) Then
                    LIB_ALBUMtpath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Albums.xml")
                Else
                    ErrorList.Add("LIB_ALBUMS")
                End If
                If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Years.xml")) Then
                    LIB_YEARtpath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Years.xml")
                Else
                    ErrorList.Add("LIB_YEARS")
                End If
                If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Genres.xml")) Then
                    LIB_GENREtpath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "Genres.xml")
                Else
                    ErrorList.Add("LIB_GENRES")
                End If
                If ErrorList.Count > 0 Then
                    e.Result = ErrorList
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Dim ARTIST_XML As New XmlDocument
                Dim ALBUMS_XML As New XmlDocument
                Dim YEARS_XML As New XmlDocument
                Dim GENRES_XML As New XmlDocument
                Try
                    ARTIST_XML.Load(LIB_ARTISTtpath)
                    ALBUMS_XML.Load(LIB_ALBUMtpath)
                    YEARS_XML.Load(LIB_YEARtpath)
                    GENRES_XML.Load(LIB_GENREtpath)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString & ": At BG_SCANNER_DoWork_READ_XML_FILE //" & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
                    MessageBox.Show(Me, "An error occured on Library files." & vbCrLf & "Check the debug console for more informations.", "Mr. Audio", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    e.Result = False
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
                BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(40)
                'Writing To Aritsts
                For Each artist As XmlNode In ARTIST_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes
                    For i As Integer = 0 To NewSongs.Count - 1
                        Try
                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(NewSongs(i))
                            If artist.FirstChild.InnerText = Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers Then
                                Dim Nsong As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                Nsong.InnerText = NewSongs(i)
                                artist.ChildNodes(1).AppendChild(Nsong)
                                artist.ChildNodes(2).InnerText += 1
                            Else
                                If NewSongs.Count > 0 Then
                                    Dim ArtOnlyList As New List(Of String)
                                    For Each song In NewSongs
                                        Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                        ArtOnlyList.Add(Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers)
                                    Next
                                    ArtOnlyList = ArtOnlyList.Distinct.ToList
                                    For Each _artist In ArtOnlyList
                                        Dim Zroot As XmlNodeList = ARTIST_XML.SelectNodes("/Mr.Audio/Artists/Artist")
                                        Dim Znode As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Artist")
                                        Dim Zname As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Name")
                                        Zname.InnerText = _artist
                                        Dim ZSongsNode As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Songs")
                                        Dim ZFirstSong As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                        Dim ZCount As XmlNode = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Count")
                                        ZCount.InnerText = 0
                                        For Each song In NewSongs
                                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                            If artist = Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers Then
                                                ZFirstSong = ARTIST_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                                ZFirstSong.InnerText = song
                                                ZSongsNode.AppendChild(ZFirstSong)
                                                ZCount.InnerText += 1
                                                Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(CType(Tagger.Tag.Tag.Pictures(0).Data.Data, Byte()))).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero).Clone.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "ArtistsPics", Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers & ".png"))
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                        Znode.AppendChild(Zname)
                                        Znode.AppendChild(ZSongsNode)
                                        Znode.AppendChild(ZCount)
                                        ARTIST_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(Znode)
                                    Next
                                End If
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                        End Try
                    Next
                Next
                ARTIST_XML.Save(LIB_ARTISTtpath)
                    BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(60)
                'Writing to albums
                For Each album As XmlNode In ALBUMS_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes
                    For i As Integer = 0 To NewSongs.Count - 1
                        Try
                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(NewSongs(i))
                            If album.FirstChild.InnerText = Tagger.Tag.Album Then
                                Dim Nsong As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                Nsong.InnerText = NewSongs(i)
                                album.ChildNodes(1).AppendChild(Nsong)
                                album.ChildNodes(2).InnerText += 1
                            Else
                                If NewSongs.Count > 0 Then
                                    Dim AlbOnlyList As New List(Of String)
                                    For Each song In NewSongs
                                        Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                        AlbOnlyList.Add(Tagger.Tag.Album)
                                    Next
                                    AlbOnlyList = AlbOnlyList.Distinct.ToList
                                    For Each _album In AlbOnlyList
                                        Dim Zroot As XmlNodeList = ALBUMS_XML.SelectNodes("/Mr.Audio/Albums/Album")
                                        Dim Znode As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Album")
                                        Dim Zname As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Name")
                                        Zname.InnerText = _album
                                        Dim ZSongsNode As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Songs")
                                        Dim ZFirstSong As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                        Dim ZCount As XmlNode = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Count")
                                        ZCount.InnerText = 0
                                        For Each song In NewSongs
                                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                            If album = Tagger.Tag.Album Then
                                                ZFirstSong = ALBUMS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                                ZFirstSong.InnerText = song
                                                ZSongsNode.AppendChild(ZFirstSong)
                                                ZCount.InnerText += 1
                                                Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(CType(Tagger.Tag.Tag.Pictures(0).Data.Data, Byte()))).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero).Clone.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "AlbumsPics", Tagger.Tag.Album & ".png"))
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                        Znode.AppendChild(Zname)
                                        Znode.AppendChild(ZSongsNode)
                                        Znode.AppendChild(ZCount)
                                        ALBUMS_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(Znode)
                                    Next
                                End If
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                        End Try
                    Next
                Next
                ALBUMS_XML.Save(LIB_ALBUMtpath)
                BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(70)
                    'Writing to years
                    For Each year As XmlNode In YEARS_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes
                        For i As Integer = 0 To NewSongs.Count - 1
                            Try
                                Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(NewSongs(i))
                                If year.FirstChild.InnerText = Tagger.Tag.Year Then
                                    Dim Nsong As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                    Nsong.InnerText = NewSongs(i)
                                    year.ChildNodes(1).AppendChild(Nsong)
                                    year.ChildNodes(2).InnerText += 1
                                Else
                                    If NewSongs.Count > 0 Then
                                        Dim YearOnlyList As New List(Of String)
                                        For Each song In NewSongs
                                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                            YearOnlyList.Add(Tagger.Tag.Year)
                                        Next
                                        YearOnlyList = YearOnlyList.Distinct.ToList
                                        For Each _Year In YearOnlyList
                                            Dim Zroot As XmlNodeList = YEARS_XML.SelectNodes("/Mr.Audio/Years/Year")
                                            Dim Znode As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Year")
                                            Dim Zname As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Name")
                                            Zname.InnerText = _Year
                                            Dim ZSongsNode As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Songs")
                                            Dim ZFirstSong As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                            Dim ZCount As XmlNode = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Count")
                                            ZCount.InnerText = 0
                                            For Each song In NewSongs
                                                Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                                If _Year = Tagger.Tag.Year Then
                                                    ZFirstSong = YEARS_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                                    ZFirstSong.InnerText = song
                                                    ZSongsNode.AppendChild(ZFirstSong)
                                                    ZCount.InnerText += 1
                                                    GenerateImage(Tagger.Tag.Year).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero).Clone.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "YearsPics", Tagger.Tag.Year & ".png"))
                                                End If
                                            Next
                                            Znode.AppendChild(Zname)
                                            Znode.AppendChild(ZSongsNode)
                                            Znode.AppendChild(ZCount)
                                            YEARS_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(Znode)
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                        Next
                    Next
                    YEARS_XML.Save(LIB_YEARtpath)
                    BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(80)
                    'Writing to genres
                    For Each genre As XmlNode In GENRES_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes
                        For i As Integer = 0 To NewSongs.Count - 1
                            Try
                                Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(NewSongs(i))
                                If genre.FirstChild.InnerText = String.Join(";", Tagger.Tag.Genres) Then
                                    Dim Nsong As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                    Nsong.InnerText = NewSongs(i)
                                    genre.ChildNodes(1).AppendChild(Nsong)
                                    genre.ChildNodes(2).InnerText += 1
                                Else
                                    If NewSongs.Count > 0 Then
                                        Dim GenreOnlyList As New List(Of String)
                                        For Each song In NewSongs
                                            Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                            GenreOnlyList.Add(String.Join(";", Tagger.Tag.Genres))
                                        Next
                                        GenreOnlyList = GenreOnlyList.Distinct.ToList
                                        For Each _Genre In GenreOnlyList
                                            Dim Zroot As XmlNodeList = GENRES_XML.SelectNodes("/Mr.Audio/Genres/Genre")
                                            Dim Znode As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Genre")
                                            Dim Zname As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Name")
                                            Zname.InnerText = _Genre
                                            Dim ZSongsNode As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Songs")
                                            Dim ZFirstSong As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                            Dim ZCount As XmlNode = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Count")
                                            ZCount.InnerText = 0
                                            For Each song In NewSongs
                                                Tagger = TagLib.File.Create(song)
                                                If _Genre = String.Join(";", Tagger.Tag.Genres) Then
                                                    ZFirstSong = GENRES_XML.CreateElement("Song")
                                                    ZFirstSong.InnerText = song
                                                    ZSongsNode.AppendChild(ZFirstSong)
                                                    ZCount.InnerText += 1
                                                    GenerateImage(String.Join(";", CType(Tagger, TagLib.File).Tag.Genres)).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero).Clone.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MrAudio", "Library", "ArtistsPics", Tagger.Tag.JoinedPerformers & ".png"))
                                                End If
                                            Next
                                            Znode.AppendChild(Zname)
                                            Znode.AppendChild(ZSongsNode)
                                            Znode.AppendChild(ZCount)
                                            GENRES_XML.LastChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(Znode)
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                        Next
                    Next
                    GENRES_XML.Save(LIB_GENREtpath)
                    BG_SCANER.ReportProgress(100)
                    settings_scanlib.Checked = False
                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToShortTimeString & ": At BG_SCANNER_DoWork //" & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.
EDIT: The XML file will contain about 500 Song depending on the user library , the code now takes about 10 mins in a 400 song library , The app currently uses 140~200 mb RAM Max

Comment: `The only problem is It's too slow [...]`. Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place since your code is actually working?

Comment: @AlexB. I didn't know this community existed i'll check it out.

Comment: The best way to deal with code that's too slow is to profile it, find out where it's slow, and figure out how to speed up that specific choke point.  Typically, the fix will be a change to algorithm or data structure to better suit the data / problem being solved.

Comment: I know where my problem is I did some researches before posting that question , the problem is with my algorithm i just don't know how to fix it

Comment: How large is the Xml File?  What is your connection string?  When you run the application how much memory are you using (check task manager)?

Comment: @jdweng Check Edit

Comment: I 100MB file will probably take a lot of memory.  When you reach 100% memory utilization You start using swap space where the memory is place in temporary file on your hard drive and then the application runs real slow.

Comment: @jdweng All 4 Xml Database files are 100Kb combined , the slowness is not in the app it's in the time it takes to organize the songs in the databases , it doesn't store the songs just the paths of the songs

Comment: @AnesHamdani Can you please narrow down a bit more what exactly is slow and mark it in the code you´ve posted? Usually I start simple and create some Stopwatches at every unit to be able to measure and make sure to optimize the right parts

Comment: @AlexB. the parts which slows down the code are 
'Writing To Aritsts
'Writing to albums
'Writing to years
'Writing to genres
Even if i use a stopwatch i can't identify where the problem is